# Can we find the eigenvalues of a linear operator where it takes a vector to its transpose?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, transpose

[image]

---

In a homework problem, we are asked to find the eigenvalues of a linear operator $T(X)= A(X)^t A$ ($A$ is a matrix, $X^t$ is $X$'s transpose). My calculation of $T(x)$ lead me to a seemingly answer, but on second thought, why is this problem possible? An eigenvector is supposed to stay on its own direction, but my calculation just shows how the "transpose of the vector" is scaled, which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: MathJax, please. Your handwriting reminds me of the Kartvelian alphabet.

Comment: My guess is that $A$ and $X$ in that formula are both square matrices of the same size, So $T$ is a linear map from the set of all $n \times n$ matrices to itself.  Perfectly OK, to ask for which $\lambda$ you can have $A X^t A = \lambda X$ for some nonzero $X$. It may help to think at the outset solely in terms of the definition of eigenvalue, and not think of matrices as having a 'direction' (although this is often the geometric picture, I'm not sure it's the most helpful intro to this problem)

Comment: I understand now.My original approach was wrong but I corrected that.Thanks!